# How to implement interface in successor

Tags: c#

I have a simple class called `Student` that inherits a base class called `Human`. Now I want to implement `IComparable` in order to be able to sort students based on their grades. But how can I implement `CompareTo()` when my class is already a successor of another class? Here is the `Student` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace Task2.Classes
{
    class Student : Human
    {
        private double grade;

        public Student(double grade, string firstName, string lastName)
            : base(firstName, lastName)
        {
            this.grade = grade;
        }

        public double Grade
        {
            get { return this.grade; }
            set { this.grade = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can chain implementations, provided there is only one class amongst them:

```
class Student : Human, IComparable<Student>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, sir. It is priceless. :)